# How can I configure my locale correctly for Spacemacs?

Tags: locale

When I start Spacemacs I get a box created out of `\u2502` sequences which I assume is the a box of  particular character or colour not rendering properly. Below is the output from the `locale` command. What settings to I have to apply globally, or in my `.bashrc` etc to fix this?

```
LANG=en_GB
LANGUAGE=:en_GB.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB"
LC_TIME="en_GB"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB"
LC_PAPER="en_GB"
LC_NAME="en_GB"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Perhaps try `en_GB.utf8` throughout (i.e. in `$LANG`), especially for `LC_CTYPE`?

Comment: @Celada I have used `export LANG=en_GB.utf8; emacs -nw` to start and those issues seem to have gone away, but I can't be sure if they have really gone. Is there some test codes I can use to verify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything specific to spacemacs, but this looks like an encoding issue.

Your character is a pretty good test already.

```
$ echo -e "\u2502" 
â
```

To set up UTF-8 encoding (which is great for ASCII data), make sure all your language variables have UTF-8 in them.

It should be enough to do:

```
export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
```

afterwards run locale to confirm it.

```
$ export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
$ export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
$ export LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Now testing it again

```
$ echo -e "\u2502" 
│
```

This, in your .bashrc, should solve it.

Make sure your terminal emulator (if any) actually uses the correct encoding too. It should properly read it from `$LC_TYPE` i believe, but some have settings to override this in their preferences.

If you also want to setup/test colors as well, make sure you have 256 colors set in your term variable

```
export TERM="xterm-256color"
```

the 256colors.pl is a nice test for this https://gist.github.com/hSATAC/1095100